# Can't access parent string from closure?

Tags: python, closures

I have some python code where I am attempting to access a string in the parent scope from a closure, but whenever I try to access it I get the error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_string' referenced before
>   assignment

What is also strange is that I have a list defined at the same scope as the string, but I have no problem access *that* variable.

I created a simplified version of the code which demonstrates the problem:

```
def test():
    def f1():
        print my_list
        print my_string
        my_string += "test"
    my_string = "1"
    my_list = [1,2,3]
    f1()
test()
```

When I execute this I get the output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    test()
  File "test.py", line 8, in test
    f1()
  File "test.py", line 4, in f1
    print my_string
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_string' referenced before assignment
```

Why am I able to access the list but not the string?  How can I go about accessing my string from my closure?

I'm new to python and closures, so if I've left something out here please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you can't modify nonlocal variables without declaring that that's what you want.  `my_string` is not a local variable, so you need to declare that you want to modify it anyway.  In Python3, you can put `nonlocal mystring` at the beginning of `f1()`.  In Python2, you would have to make it a global variable.  To do that, you need `global mystring` at the beginning of `test()` *and* at the beginning of `f1()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've always heard that using `global` was a big no-no, do you think that using it here would be the best solution?  Also - why is it that my list variable is accessible when I am using it in the exact same way as my string variable?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to return the string instead, and add to `my_string` outside of `f1()`.  The `print` call is not really the problem.  If you remove `my_string += "test"`, you will see that it prints just fine.  I'm sorry, though that I can't say why it points to that line in the SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

Change my_string variable to list or any other object types to get desired behaviour. Use of str vs. list is the issue. Nothing to do with closures.
Inspecting the base clases of str and list shows the difference

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmro(str)
(<type 'str'>, <type 'basestring'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> inspect.getmro(list)
(<type 'list'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> #taking one step further
... 
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s[0]
'h'
 >>> s[0] = 'y'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

Insert a line "print locals()" in the inner f1 and notice that my_string is not even a local
        print '#f1: locals', locals()